# How to change gray level of Dicom image?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, dicom, grayscale

I am working gray images in which gray level lies 0 to 255 . I want to work on Dicom images but maximum gray level of dicom image is grater than 255. I just want to know that how to change dicom image with maximum gray level 255.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It sounds like you're asking a more general question about how to display a grayscale image with >8bpp on an 8bpp target. Most grayscale DICOM images are stored with more than 8-bits per pixel and a suggested window+level are used to adjust the data for an 8-bit display.

Comment: I would be reluctant to lose that much precision from the images. As far as I remember, the built-in functions in Matlab that operate on grayscale images will work on int16 or double images just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can normalize the images so that they have a range of `[0,1]`.  Once you do this, you can scale the image by 255 to bring this to a range of `[0,255]`.  Assuming your image is stored in `im`, you can do this:

```
im = double(im);
im = (im - min(im(:))) / (max(im(:)) - min(im(:))); %// Normalize to 0-1
im = uint8(255*im); %// Scale to 255
```

`min(im(:))` will find the minimum intensity of your entire image while `max(im(:))` will find the maximum intensity of your entire image.  Note that once I scale the image, I cast to `uint8` as this will the proper data type associated with this intensity range.

However, MATLAB has functionality that already normalizes between `[0,1]` with [`im2double`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/im2double.html).  This takes in an image of any precision and normalizes the image to `[0,1]`.  You can then take this output, multiply by 255 and cast to `uint8`:

```
im = uint8(255*im2double(im));
```